# Здраствуйте не могу найти ошибку в коде и сделать в каждую кнопку по одной функции: чтобы круг двигался по прямой останавливался и и шёл обратно

Tags: javascript, html, button, setinterval

```
               <div id="divSetInterval">
</div>

          <button id="startKula">Start</button>

<script>

    let szerokoscOknaAnimacji = window.innerWidth;

    let wysokoscOknaAnimacji = window.innerHeight;

    let animowanyDivSetInterval = document.getElementById('divSetInterval');

    animowanyDivSetInterval.style.position = 'relative';

    let pozycjaLeftDivSetInterval = 1;

    function ruszDivSetInterval() {

        if (pozycjaLeftDivSetInterval < szerokoscOknaAnimacji - 400) {

            let ruchDivSetnterval = 1;

            pozycjaLeftDivSetInterval = pozycjaLeftDivSetInterval +
                ruchDivSetnterval;

            
            animowanyDivSetInterval.style.left = pozycjaLeftDivSetInterval + 'px';

        }
    }
    document.getElementById("startKula").addEventListener('click' , startFunction);

    function startFunction()

    zmiennaSetInt = setInterval(ruszDivSetInterval, 1);
```

Comment: `function startFunction()` --- эта строка что делает?

Comment: Вроде бы в этой функции находится zmiennaSetInt которая ровна setInterval и запускает функцию ruszDivSetInterval

Comment: нет, в этой функции ничего не находится... т.к. написана она неправильно